# Mysql #1235 error code, when create 2 triggers with different purposes

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a trigger that created in phpmyadmin, like :

```
BEGIN
UPDATE bands SET 
bands.status = "active"
where bands.id IN(
SELECT * FROM
(select bands.id 
from bands where bands.id IN 
(select bandId from invites join bands 
on(invites.bandId = bands.id) 
where invites.status="approved" 
group by bandId having count(invites.status)=bands.total_personel))AS X);
end
```

This trigger will changes my bands status to active.

But I want to change the status automatically to "inactive" too, if it doesn't meet the where clause.

If I create another trigger like :

```
BEGIN
UPDATE bands SET 
bands.status = "inactive"
where bands.id IN(
SELECT * FROM
(select bands.id 
from bands where bands.id IN 
(select bandId from invites join bands 
on(invites.bandId < bands.id) 
where invites.status="approved" 
group by bandId having count(invites.status)=bands.total_personel))AS X);
end
```

Mysql gives me #1235 error code.

How can I resolve this problem? or is there a way to combine these purposes in just one trigger?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. I don't know before that UPDATE command can be combined with WHEN condition to.

Here the code :

```
BEGIN
UPDATE bands SET status = CASE
WHEN bands.id IN
(SELECT * FROM
(select bands.id from bands where bands.id IN 
(select bandId from invites join bands 
 on(invites.bandId = bands.id) 
 where invites.status="approved" 
 group by bandId having count(invites.status)=bands.total_personel))AS X) 
 then "active"
 ELSE "inactive"
 END
 WHERE bands.id in (select distinct invites.bandId from invites);
 END
```

That Mysql code changes the status to active if meets the when condition, and automatically changes the status to inactive if it doesn't meet the WHEN condition.

Comment: I believe you've made an error in this trigger that you will discover later, once you have more data.  You are updating rows in "bands" that have nothing to do with the row whose update fired the trigger.  Triggers in MySQL fire once *per row*, and the row is accessible as special pseudo-tables called NEW and OLD.  You should probably be matching on NEW.bandId.  Otherwise this trigger gets slower over time.